# Galera throws “WSREP has not yet prepared …” error but nodes are working

Tags: galera

Yesterday we moved from 2 node Galera to 4 node Galera with a brand new infrastructure. But after we move the database, Galera started throwing "WSREP has not yet prepared node for application use" error. However all 4 nodes are operational.

New symptom: This error comes from only one table :/

Setup;

- Galera is working with 4 nodes
- All 4 nodes are in the same local network
- There is no network connectivity issue
- There is no disk issue (or IO)

We tried these but;

- Increasing CPU did not help
- Increasing RAM did not help
- Changing config for auto_increment_increment to 4 did not help
- Changing config query_cache_size=0 did not help
- Database fix didnt work

Symthoms;

- New disks are all SSD, so I dont think there is a slow IO issue
- Constantly monitoring them but WSREP is always in sync
- Not always throwing errors
- Cannot insert to a specific table and it gives errors with that table most of the time

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Is there a resolution for this?